# State of Git changes in a file does not change after being committed

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

My problem/question is whether it is possible to make VScode's native source control reflect committed Git changes without having pushed them first to the repository.

For example, to make the changes to the right "disappear" in VScode's source control, I have to not only stage and commit but also push these changes:
[image]

The changes disappear from VScode's source control even if the push wasn't successful.

I'd like to commit the changes one by one and have them reflected in the right tab on the picture after every commit. At the same time, a push event should be issued just once after all of the commits are done.

Comment: There is no such thing as Git committing "changes" so what are we talking about here?

Comment: I made some clarifying edits to the question. Still not sure what's wrong with 'Git committing "changes" '. I select a chunk of code, run a VScode command 'Stage selected ranges', and commit the staged changes. The problem is that VScode's source control still recognizes this piece of code as 'changes' and includes it in the differences up until I push the commit to remote. I'd like to have the 'changes' UI updated without the push.

Comment: A Git commit is a complete snapshot of your project. The way staging works is that you can think of the staging area as a separate copy of your working directory. Initially, that copy is identical to the currently checked-out commit, but as you stage changes from your working directory, a staged change is "applied" to the copy. When you finally commit, only the changes you staged appear in that commit.

Comment: What you are describing is consistent with your file being compared to the remote branch, not your local tracking branch, to decide what has changed. I don't know enough about VSCode to know how that state of affairs could come to pass.

Comment: "Still not sure what's wrong with 'Git committing "changes"" Because that is not what Git does, and is not what Git is. It might help to read my https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/.

Comment: @chepner, you are right, comparing to the remote instead of the local branch is exactly the problem I'd like to clarify

Comment: weird... I smell bug. check https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3Adiff-editor+inline+label%3Abug. if you don't see an existing ticket, raise one and comment here with a link to your ticket.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/203483